# Lighting inside transparent material is not working ideally. (Cycles, Ray Visibility Uncheck shadow not working)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

I am creating a house exterior and setting lighting from inside the house. However, the point light through the glass (transmission = 1.0) looks like a ball along with its radius.

Could you please advise how I can make it naturally?
In eevee, it does not have this problem.

I uncheck on the glass material Object Property > Ray Visibility > Shadow but not working

[image]

Node for glass
[image]

Light Setting
[image]

Render Properties
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add images of the nodes used for the glass and also show the settings for the lights.

Comment: >susu I have uploaded photos.